# How this device "Electronic Anti-lost-Anti-theft-Flashlight" measure distance?

Tags: rf, measurement, distance

Sorry i don't speak english but ill try.

We want to design a system of a receiver and transmitter in RF, that it "beeps" when it is a certain distance one of each other.

I found this: [http://www.amazon.com/Electronic-Anti-lost-Anti-theft-Flashlight-receivers/dp/B00QNE6QWI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QNE6QWI)

It works 433.92M Hz.

So my question is, how this system measure the distance? i want to design something like that.

Sorry for my bad english, ill hope was understandable.

Comment: I really doubt that the designer of that product is here to explain how it works.

Comment: It does not measure distance ! The remote just transmits a code and the corresponding receiver then beeps if it is within range. If the receiver is too far away or inside a metal box, it will not beep.

Comment: BAsicly the same as remote car lock, when you are in range and  press the button the car onlocks/locks and flashes, if outside the range you an press the buttons as much you want.

Answer (score 2):

That system doesn't measure distance.
It works like this:

1. You push a button on the transmitter.
2. The transmitter sends a coded signal.
3. The receiver decodes the signal and beeps if it is the correct code for that receiver.

The only "distance measurement" that goes on there is that if the receiver is too far away from the transmitter then it can't pick up the signal from the transmitter and so doesn't beep.

Your only real option is to use a low power transmitter that is on all the time.  When the receiver picks up the signal, then it beeps.  Since the transmitter is low power (REALLY low) the receiver will only beep if you get close enough to it.

You can calibrate the transmit strength to make the receiver beep when you get within a desired range.  Objects (like walls and furniture and people) that get in the way will, of course, block part of the signal and shorten the range.

Anything else, and you are going to need a lot of stuff that gets too expensive and bulky to be using as a key finder - if you can do it reliably at all.

---

For anti-theft, you keep the transmitter on all the time and invert the operation of the receiver.

So long as it receives the signal from the transmitter, it stays quiet.
It beeps when it loses the signal.

You just need to make sure that your beeper has a greater range than the transmitter.

Comment: You beat me. Rats.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast:  Quickdraw McGraw  :)

Comment: Makes me curious how the "Anti-Theft" aspect works. Perhaps the thief is sporting enough to keep the loot within transmitter range?

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  Me, too.  The blurb claims anti-theft, but the description doesn't mention it.  :shrug:  Marketroids.